# Is Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ a mispelling or a variant?

Tags: onomastics

In my edition of the Septuagint which is Brenton 1851 reprinted in 2018, the name for the Assyrian king of XIV Kings 15-16 is:

> Θαλγαθφελλασὰρ

which is Thalgathphellasar. However, in many online versions of the Septuagint I see this spelling:

> Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ

which is Thaglathphellasar. So, it would appear to be a transposition of letters gamma and lambda. Are these variants in the text or is one of them a typo?

Answer (score 1):

In my version of LXX, Rahlfs 1979 ed., the name Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ occurs in the following places with some variants noted:

- 2 Kings 15:29 - Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ; Swete's LXX: Ἀλγαθφελλασὰρ; The footnotes to Rahlfs suggest that manuscripts have the following variants on this name at this location: Ἀλγαθφελλασὰρ, Θαλγαθφελλασὰρ, Θαγλαθφαλσὰρ, etc.  The latter occurring often as in other places.
- 2 Kings 16:7 - Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ; Swete's LXX: Θαλγαθφελλασὰρ; Similar variants Rahlfs' list as for 2 Kings 15:29.  The variant in both places includes the observation that Θαγλαθφαλσὰρ occurs quite often in the MSS.
- 2 Kings 16:10 - Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ; Swete's LXX: Θαλγαλφελλασὰρ;  Rahlfs lists no variants here but implies numerous variants by his comment in the footnote in 2 Kings 15:29.
- 1 Chron 5:6 - Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ; Swete's LXX: Θαλγαβανάσαρ;  Rahlfs lists Θαλγαβανασὰρ as a variant in the MSS.
- 1 Chron 5:26 -  Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ; Swete's LXX: Θαγναφαμάσαρ;  Rahlfs lists another variant Θαγναφαμασὰρ;
- 2 Chron 28:20 - Θαγλαθφελλασὰρ; Swete's LXX: Θαλγαφελλάδαρ; Rahlfs lists several more variants.

Thus, the spelling of this king's name was far from uniform in the original MSS and numerous spellings were used.

For completeness Jerome's Vulgate uniformly has "Theglathfalassar".